# Does SSMS' IntelliSense have a feature similar to Visual Studio XML documentation comments / support database object summaries?

Tags: documentation, intellisense, ssms, xml-documentation

When writing .NET code in Visual Studio, I can attach a XML documentation comment to a method to provide IntelliSense with a summary for it. For example:

```cs
// <summary>
//  This method fiddles the frobble.
// </summary>
void FiddleTheFrobble() { … }
```

(That summary is then shown when the mouse is placed over the method's name for some time, or along with an auto-complete suggestion.)

Does a similar feature exist in SQL Server Management Studio for documenting database objects (tables, views, stored procedures, UDFs, etc.)? Perhaps by setting a specific extended property, or by preceding the object definition by a comment?

If yes, how do I provide a IntelliSense summary for a database object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. T-SQL editor in SSMS don't support XML-Comments from C#/VB.NET language.

But if you will use full Visual Studio for developing/maintaining database schema, then there is "Description" field with absolutly same purpose:

[image: Description field in proprety Window]

Visual Studio will store it's content in database using extended properties.

SSMS is just not designed for developing big, compicated database projects. It's for Managenent.

Comment: I like that database of yours.

Answer (score 1):

[This Simple Talk article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/towards-the-self-documenting-sql-server-database/) describes how to set the MS_Description for database objects.

Once set, there are various documentation tools available that will pull out these values. Commercial tools available from the vendor I work for are [SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/), which documents the entire database and its objects, and [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/), which is primarily an auto-completion tool, but it also show the extended properties for objects when you hover over the object in a query window with the mouse cursor.

Comment: While I wasn't really looking for 3rd party tools, it's nice to know that there are some good ones out there. Thank you!